# Temp data is not being maintained between two controllers sitecore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, sitecore

I am just trying to implement Post-Redirect-Get pattern in my sitecore application.

I could see Tempdata is not maintained when i redirect from one controller to another controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Select()
    {
        TempData["SelectPost"] = "SomeValue";
        var path = PaymentPath;
        return RedirectToRoute(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, new { pathInfo = path}); 
    }

    public ActionResult Payment()
    {
        var tempDataValue = TempData["SelectPost"];
        //Value is coming as null always
    }
```

I even tried with **RedirectToAction** and **Redirect** and also by explicitly calling **TempData.keep()**

All my pages are controller renderings.

Am i missing anything? I am using Sitecore.NET 7.0. (rev. 130424)

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` is available to the current and next request only. So if you `POST` to `/select` and redirect to `/payment` (`GET`) the `TempData` value will be available.

In your example it looks like you are redirecting to the `SitecoreRouteName` and *then* redirecting to `/payment`, in which case your `TempData` value will no longer be available.

If you need to store something for longer than the current and next request I suggest you use `Session`, a cookie or a database to store your value.

Comment: I tried using RedirectToAction too but still the TempData is null.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you do the redirect, `TempData` only lasts for 2 hops - the current request and the next request. You are trying to do three - `Select > SiteCoreRouteName > Payment`.